# Twilio MMS Send Local File

Tags: salesforce, twilio, mms

We can send MMS using Twilio api in Salesforce.
As i know that using that code i can send MMS using Twilio in Salesforce.

[Sending a MMS](http://twilio-salesforce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/messages.html)

```
properties.add(new TwilioNameValuePair('MediaUrl','https://www.twilio.com/packages/company/img/logos_downloadable_round.png'));
```

But it's seams that we have need to pass media file url.
But how can we take a input of file form Local machine and send them using Twilio MMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajendra, hello! Megan from Twilio here.

This sounds similar to what I ran into building an [OpenCV MMS implementation in this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/11/getting-started-with-opencv-and-python-featuring-the-martian-2.html).

The example there is in Python specifically, after writing an image to my local filesystem and making the desired modifications on it, I send it through:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER,
                               filename)
```

which handles the delivery of the following [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml):

```
 message.media('http://YourNgrokURL/uploads/{}'.format(filename))
```

You'll be needing the equivalent of Flask's `send_from_directory` to handle this in your implementation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI Megan,

Thank you for your quick reply.

So according to this if i will pass a path of local file in MMS media URL then i will work.

for Example : E:\rajan\Pictures\Camera_Roll/Raj.png.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: What Megan is saying here is that you will need to build a way to serve up your local files through a web server so that you can point to them at a URL. In the example shown, uploaded files were placed in a particular `UPLOAD_FOLDER` and Megan created a route in her application that then looked up a filename in that folder and sent the file back. You could do the same for your Camera_Roll folder, though I'm not sure what language/framework you're working with, so can't suggest how to do it.

Comment: Hi Philnash, yes that now make sense. I am using Salesforce with Apex Language for sending SMS.

Comment: hi megan I had this question 3.5 years later and this was very helpful, thank you for this haha

Answer (score 2):

You can use twilio assets for sending local files. 
- First you need to upload the local files on twilio assets.
- use the assets url and media url for sending Mms

Answer (score 0):

I understand the twilio requirement (now, I think), but I consider this process to be a **major** pain.  It just drastically ups the number of things I need to do. Run a server, serve up the file, validate the request, remove access to the file once it is served.

All I really want to do is send a "one off" mms message with one or more local files.  I don't want these files publicly available.  I don't want to store it indefinitely.  I just want a "fire and forget".  That is, after it is sent twilio should forget all about it.   I really don't understand why this would be so difficult for twilio to implement. While it may not be the typical use case, I'd think it would be a relatively common use case.

It isn't clear if it is safe for me to remove access to the local file immediately after twilio requests it once, or if I need it hang around indefinitely in case twilio needs it around in case of a retry of some sort.

Yes, I can do it, but I shouldn't need to.

Sorry about refreshing an old thread.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've resolved the issue.  IMO some of the documentation was unclear, but that might have been in my head.