# Set Reply To In Twilio SMS

Tags: sms, twilio

When we send sms from twilio then we want to set reply to phone number.

So if they reply to the outbound message then incoming message will be received by agent not the twilio number form which we are sending sms.

Thanks,

Rajendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is no concept of a "reply-to" phone number in SMS messages. The recipient of a message can reply to the number that sent the message to them.

If you are looking to try to connect users directly through a Twilio number, I recommend you check out the [Twilio Masked Number tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/php/laravel) (that links to the PHP version, but there are other language versions of the tutorial). It will show you how to use a pool of numbers so that you can maintain a relationship between an agent and a user.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Ok Thanks, yes its helped me.

Comment: If we use https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-i-use-a-non-twilio-number-as-the-caller-id-for-outgoing-calls non twilio number then if receiver reply to message then who will receive the SMS? Twilio Number OR Non-Twilio Number?

Comment: You can only set the caller ID to a non Twilio number when making phone calls, you can't do it for SMS messages.

Comment: No problem! Any other questions, just ask here on SO and we'll try to help!

Comment: Can you please reply to my that question also regarding twilio MMS : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629693/twilio-mms-send-local-file/36633123#36633123