# Failing to send media with Twilio Whatsapp Sandbox API?

Tags: curl, twilio, whatsapp

Failing to send media via Twilio WhatsApp API using `CURL`, I only receive the text message but media is missing.

I been going through Twilio docs for sending media files. The command finishes correctly but on my phone I only receive the message [Send Media with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/whatsapp-media-support)

curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json --data-urlencode "To=whatsapp:+263000000" --data-urlencode "From=whatsapp:+14155238886" --data-urlencode "Body=Thanks for contacting me on WhatsApp! Here is a picture of an owl." --data-urlencode “MediaUrl=https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png” -u "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx:authkey"

It should deliver an image file of owl to recipient in WhatsApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I used your cURL code which is from both the [WhatsApp Media Support blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/whatsapp-media-support) and the [Support page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017961894-Sending-and-Receiving-Media-with-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio-Beta-). This recreated your error: the `numMedia` Message property did not exist, but the message sent. A Message SID existed, but when I visited the subresource media URI, it said the requested resource was not found, status 404, and it gave this [20404](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404) error page.

I found switching the double quotation marks around the image URL to single quotations to send the image (making `numMedia` and the subresource media URI exist. After the single quotations, using double quotations around the media URL did work as well so an image was sent.

`curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json --data-urlencode "To=whatsapp:+263000000" --data-urlencode "From=whatsapp:+14155238886" --data-urlencode "Body=Thanks for contacting me on WhatsApp! Here is a picture of an owl." --data-urlencode 'MediaUrl=https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png' -u "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx:authkey"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any way to refer to a local image file in server using PHP for the mediaURL? Examples only show https hosted image url.

Comment: It cannot be local, must be hosted somewhere it can be publicly-accessed, ie. with Twilio Assets. This could mean writing it to your local file storage as my former teammate Megan did here in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629693/twilio-mms-send-local-file